# How to use a custom type as a column in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How can I use a complex type like an int to query the database?

I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID  |  Name
----+-------
1   |  Foo
2   |  Bar
```

and I have an entity that looks like this:

```
[Table("MyEntityTable")]
public class MyEntity{
    [Column("ID")]
    public CustomId ID {get;set;}
    [Column("Name")]
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
public class CustomId {
    public int ID => GetId();
    public object SomeObject {get;set;}

    public CustomId(object o){
        SomeObject = o;
    }

    private int GetId() => //logic returns a unique ID that maps to database column.
}
```

How can I tell entity framework that when something is a `CustomId` it should only map the `int` portion to the specified column and ignore the rest?

So I can do something like:

```
var id = new CustomId(myObject);
var entity = db.MyEntitys.First(e => e.ID == id);
```

Comment: You don't, that wont work. You map custom types to tables and public properties within that type (*of atomic types like string, int, decimal, etc*) to columns. If you want **relationships** then you have custom types as properties but that type should then correspond to another table so you can setup a proper table relationship.

Comment: @Igor but it *is* mapped with an atomic type. In the database it's an int, and CustomId is really an int that is generated by constructing it using an object

Comment: `class CustomId` is not an atomic type and EF can not map it. Any type you define outside of an enumeration will not be considered as an atomic type as far as it working with EF.

Comment: @Igor I know CustomId isn't atomic, but the only bit entity framework should care about is atomic. Surely there's a way of telling EF how to deal with a CustomId? Some way of saying, if you want to search by CustomId just send the database the ID and it'll give you the correct bit.

Comment: EF can't translate that into a stored query which is why it is not supported. There is no known mechanism to translate arbitrary linq expressions into stored expressions (ie. sql) which is why you are limited to atomic types (among other things).

Comment: @Igor exactly, among other things, like datetime! Is there no way to specify how it should generate the expression? So when EF sees it, it sees (e => e == myCustomId) and translates it to (e => e.ID == myCustomId.ID)? Anyway, perhaps it's just a feature that doesn't exist yet.